# Generate random numbers by group with replacement

Tags: r, random, sample

** edited because I'm a doofus - with replacement, not without **

I have a large-ish (>500k rows) dataset with 421 groups, defined by two grouping variables.   Sample data as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(group_one=rep((0:9),26), group_two=rep((letters),10))

head(df)

  group_one group_two
1         0         a
2         1         b
3         2         c
4         3         d
5         4         e
6         5         f
```

...and so on.

What I want is some number (k = 12 at the moment, but that number may vary) of stratified samples, by membership in (group_one x group_two).  Membership in each group should be indicated by a new column, sample_membership, which has a value of 1 through k (again, 12 at the moment).  I should be able to subset by sample_membership and get up to 12 distinct samples, each of which is representative when considering group_one and group_two.

Final data set would thus look something like this:

```
  group_one group_two sample_membership
1         0         a                 1  
2         0         a                12
3         0         a                 5
4         1         a                 5
5         1         a                 7
6         1         a                 9
```

Thoughts?  Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Your title says "without replacement", but your question doesn't mention it. Do you want sampling without replacement (and you guarantee <= 12 rows per grouping)?

Comment: That's an error.  Should definitely be with replacement.  My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question title to correct the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a one-line `data.table` approach, which you should definitely consider if you have a long `data.frame`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, sample_membership := sample.int(12, .N, replace=TRUE), keyby = .(group_one, group_two)]

df
#    group_one group_two sample_membership
#   1:         0         a                 9
#   2:         0         a                 8
#   3:         0         c                10
#   4:         0         c                 4
#   5:         0         e                 9
# ---                                      
# 256:         9         v                 4
# 257:         9         x                 7
# 258:         9         x                11
# 259:         9         z                 3
# 260:         9         z                 8
```

For sampling without replacement, use `replace=FALSE`, but as noted elsewhere, make sure you have fewer than *k* members per group.  **OR:**

If you want to use "sampling without unnecessary replacement" (making this up -- not sure what the right terminology is here) because you have more than *k* members per group but still want to keep the groups as evenly sized as possible, you could do something like:

```
# example with bigger groups
k <- 12L
big_df <- data.frame(group_one=rep((0:9),260), group_two=rep((letters),100))
setDT(big_df)

big_df[, sample_round := rep(1:.N, each=k, length.out=.N), keyby = .(group_one, group_two)]
big_df[, sample_membership := sample.int(k, .N, replace=FALSE), keyby = .(group_one, group_two, sample_round)]
head(big_df, 15) # you can see first repeat does not occur until row k+1
```

Within each "sampling round" (first k observations in the group, second k observations in the group, etc.) there is sampling without replacement.  Then, if necessary, the next sampling round makes all k assignments available again.

This approach would really evenly stratify the sample (but perfectly even is only possible if you have a multiple of k members in each group).

Answer (score 8):

Maybe something like this?:

```
library(dplyr)
  df %>% 
    group_by(group_one, group_two) %>% 
    mutate(sample_membership = sample(1:12, n(), replace = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R method, that assumes that your data.frame is sorted by groups:

```
# get number of observations for each group
groupCnt <- with(df, aggregate(group_one, list(group_one, group_two), FUN=length))$x

# for reproducibility, set the seed
set.seed(1234)    
# get sample by group
df$sample <- c(sapply(groupCnt, function(i) sample(12, i, replace=TRUE)))
```

Comment: This is great, but it appears that there are some (group_one x group_two) combinations with zero members, and thus groupCnt ends up with some NAs.  If I swap in zeros for those NAs, it ends up that df$sample has way fewer rows than df does, and so that fails.  Thoughts?

Comment: It appears to work in your example. Could you provide a data.frame where this happens? `aggregate` creates a data.frame with only the combinations of group 1 and group 2 that are present. Since groupCnt is constructed using the `length` function, it shouldn't produce NAs.

Comment: One possibility is that you have more than 12 observations per group in your original data. If this is the case, you will either have to limit the sample to the first 12 (or randomly selected 12), sample with replacement within each group, or increase k above the maximum number per group.

Comment: I do have more than 12 in each group, and I do need to sample with replacement - my mistake was in the title.  My apologies.

Comment: @seehuus I've edited my answer to reflect sampling with replacement. Please consider editing your question as suggested by gregor above.

Answer (score 0):

Untested example using `dplyr`, if it doesn't work it might point you in the right direction.

```
library( dplyr )
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  group_one = as.integer( runif( 1000, 1, 6) ),
  group_two = sample( LETTERS[1:6], 1000, TRUE)
) %>%
  group_by( group_one, group_two ) %>%
  mutate(
    sample_membership = sample( seq(1, length(group_one) ), length(group_one), FALSE)
  )
```

Good luck!

Comment: FYI you can use `dplyr::n()` in place of `length(group_one)` just saves a bit of typing.

Comment: Thanks, although this does a random distribution from 1 to the number of items in (group_one x group_two), and doesn't peak at 12.  I wonder if I could divide the number of items in each group by 12 and round/truncate.  I will consider.  Thanks again!